# Monkey Year Teaching (Drikung-Kagyu)

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, vajrayana

My questions concern Monkey Year Teaching held by Kagyu lineage (Great Phowa of Chagtsugma).

Is this type of Phowa similar for all Monkey Year Teachings held through the Kagyu lineage?

What is the destination land and deity of this Phowa?

Are there specific samayas and life-long obligations related to this teaching?